# Loop through map from Viewable in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jersey, mapping, jstl

So I am trying to loop through a map which I retrieve from a `Viewable`. It's working with single attributes or whatever but somehow it doesn't allow me to loop through a list. Any suggestions?

If you got a better idea passing objects than using Viewable feel free to let me know!

Thank you guys in advance.

Controller:

```
    @GET
@Path("home")
public Viewable showHome() {
    Map <String, Location> map = init();
    return new Viewable("/WEB-INF/home.jsp", map);
}

private HashMap init() {
    Map <String, Location> map = new HashMap <String, Location>();
    Location location1 = new Location("A");
    Location location2 = new Location("B");
    map.put("1", location1);
    map.put("2", location2);
    return (HashMap) map;
}
```

home.jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:if test="${it != null}">
        <c:forEach var="location" items="${it}">
             Location: <c:out value="${location.name}" />
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to loop through a map. You need to loop the Entrys then get the location with entry.value.name, value being the Location. See [How to loop through a HashMap in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1835683/2587435)

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it different for `applicationScopes`? Or is it because of the map?