# Print hashmap value in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, hashmap

I am trying to call a `HashMap` value in jsp page but got error there and error says

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   For input string: "res"

My code;

```
<c:forEach items="${onlineExamList}" var="item"
                                        varStatus="loop">

                                        <div>
                                            <b>${item.question1}</b><br>

                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label><input type="radio" value="a"
                                                    name="answers[${loop.index}]">${item.option1}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label><input type="radio" value="b"
                                                    name="answers[${loop.index}]">${item.option2}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label><input type="radio" value="c"
                                                    name="answers[${loop.index}]">${item.option3}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label><input type="radio" value="d"
                                                    name="answers[${loop.index}]">${item.option4}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" name="rightAnswer"
                                                value="${item.rightAnswer}">



//problem in this line
                                            <c:if test="${result != null}">
                                                <br>
                                                <br>
                                                <b>Your answer: ${result.get("res"+loop.index).get(1)}</b>

                                                <br>
                                            </c:if>
                                        </div>

                                        <hr />
                                    </c:forEach>
```

And this is how i have set hashmap from controller

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapResult = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        int totalScore = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < answers.answers.size(); i++) {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            String res = "Wrong";
            if (answers.answers.get(i).equals(answers.rightAnswer.get(i))) {
                res = "Correct";
                totalScore+=10;
            }

            result.add(res);
            result.add(answers.answers.get(i));
            result.add(answers.rightAnswer.get(i));

            mapResult.put("res" + i, result);
        }

        ra.addFlashAttribute("result", mapResult);
        ra.addFlashAttribute("score", totalScore);
```

Same things printed on java page

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(mapResult.get("res" + i).get(0));
            System.out.println(mapResult.get("res" + i).get(1));
            System.out.println(mapResult.get("res" + i).get(2));
            System.out.println("...................................");;
        }
```

How can I print hashmap value in jsp page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through a HashMap in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp)

Comment: Basic rule is, if you see a 500 error, issue is with your server code, no issue with JSP code. post the stack trace as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by concating the string using `concat` like this

```
${result.get("res".concat(loop.index)).get(1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check try this.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${currentLoggedInUsersMap}" var="entry">
    Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: That value should be printed inside another for loop and i should get a loop index. I dont thik this gonna work. 
Do you have another idea else?

Comment: did you tried it ? it will be print all hashmap value according to your requiremet.

Comment: That's not the reason，it is caused by`${result.get("res"+loop.index).get(1)}`

Comment: can you look at my question again please. I have updated it

Comment: for that approach you can use as well

 <% for(int i = 0; i < allFestivals.size(); i+=1) { %>
        <tr>      
            <td><%=allFestivals.get(i).getFestivalName()%></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>

Answer (score 0):

The mapResult object is a map containing string arrays
`Hashmap<String, List<String>>`
you may need to first get the Array from the map object and then iterate over it.
this may help?
`<table>
        <c:forEach var="results" items="${resultsMap['res' + loop.index]}" varStatus="loop">
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="answer" items="${results}" varStatus="status">
                    <td>
                        <td>$answer</td>
                    </td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>

    </table>`

Comment: Hello sir can i get your gmail or any mail services